# How to extend Django Oauth Toolkit?

Tags: python, django, oauth, oauth-2.0, django-views

I'm relatively new to Django and currently using Django Oauth Toolkit for implicit Oauth. It handles generating tokens and redirecting users to the correct url without issues. I haven't even needed to touch my login page code except for passing the redirect correctly.

My urls.py of course has:

```
url(r'^oauth2/', include('oauth2_provider.urls', namespace='oauth2_provider')),
```

Up until now I haven't needed to do anything custom because it works so great out of the box.
However now I need to store additional information on the OAuth AccessTokens, for example the OS the that the token comes from.
I've created this model for that:

```
class AccessTokenDetail(models.Model):
    access_token = models.OneToOneField(AccessToken, primary_key=True)
    os_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

So my plan is: after the library creates the token, capture a parameter in the request and create an `AccessTokenDetail` object. I see that I could use the [mixins](https://django-oauth-toolkit.readthedocs.org/en/latest/views/details.html#mixins), but since I'm not touching the third party library at all I'm a bit confused on which class to put them on.

How can I add this functionality?